# Logarithm in $2$-adic numbers.

Tags: logarithms, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> 1. How can we find the first $10$ digits of $\dfrac{\log 5}{\log 13}$ in the $2$-adic numbers?
>    I mean how can we write down $\{ a_i\}_{i=0}^{10}$'s **explicitly**,
>    in $\dfrac{\log 5}{\log 13}=:\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i 2^i$.

---

**Motivation** for asking this question:

Let's consider the set of prime numbers that are congruent to $5$ modulo $8$:

$$\{5, 13; 29, 37; 53, 61; 101, 109; 149, 157; 173, 181; 197, \cdots\}.$$

For any prime $p$ in this set we have $v_2(p-1)=2$.
From now on we assume that $2 \leq n$.
With a little work,
we can show that $\displaystyle{{\rm order}_{2^n}p = 2^{n-2}}$.
This implies that $p$ is a generator for the index $2$ subgroup
$$H:=\{a\in \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{2^n\mathbb{Z}} \mid a \stackrel{4}{\equiv} 1\},$$
of $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{2^n\mathbb{Z}}$.
Considering these facts,
we can find that $\overline{\langle p\rangle}=1+4\mathbb{Z}_2$,
in the $2$-adic topology.

Now let $p_1=5$ and $p_2=13$. I am not sure, but I think we can conclude that $5=13^z$, for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

> 2. I can not see why should we have $\dfrac{\log p}{\log q} \in \mathbb{Z}_2$,
>    for arbitrary prime numbers $p,q \stackrel{8}{\equiv} 5$.

Comment: A method for doing p-adic computations by hand is given here on an example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/839811

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can do it by hand, but it is much easier using a calculator (just as you do calculations of real numbers).

Paste the following into [this site](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) and press "Evaluate" to see the result.

```
F= Zp(2)
print(F)
print(log(F(5))/log(F(13)))
```

Output:

```
2-adic Ring with capped relative precision 20
1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^8 + 2^9 + 2^10 + 2^13 + 2^15 + 2^17 + O(2^18)
```

---

2. Because $\log$ is an isometry from $1 + 4\Bbb Z_2$ to $4\Bbb Z_2$ (which is an easy exercise). Thus for every $p \equiv 5\mod 8$, we have $$v_2(\log(p)) = v_2(\log(p) - \log(1)) = v_2(p - 1) = 2,$$ and hence the quotient $\log(p)/\log(q)$ has $2$-adic valuation $0$.

Comment: I have two questions. The first one is about the terminology and definition: What does "isometry" meant here? Do we mean it is a distance preserving transformation? (If yes, then it is clear that $v_2(\log x)=v_2(x)$, and the second question is answered as you've explained it.) The second problem is that I do not know how should I calculate it by hand.

Comment: For the first one, yes, it preserves the $2$-adic distance. For the second one, just use the definition of $\log(1 + x)$, which is $\log(1 + x) = \frac x 1 - \frac {x^2} 2 + \frac {x^3} 3 - \frac {x^4} 4 + \dots$. You'll see that the terms get smaller and smaller ($2$-adically). Try to add up to $5$ terms to get a feeling of what's happening.

Comment: I am sorry for asking too many questions. Yet I can not see how the logarithm expansion will help us to calculate. Could you please briefly explain how could we find $a_0=a_1=1$? Also, could you please introduce me to a link or a note, which contains a proof for the fact that $\log$ is an isometry?

Comment: $|\log(a)-\log(b)|_2= |\log(a/b)-\log(1)|_2= |\log(a/b)|_2= |a/b-1|_2 = |a-b|_2$ for $a,b\in 1+4 \Bbb{Z}_2$  where I used $\log (1+x)(1+y)=\log(1+ x) +\log (1+y)$ as formal series with rational coefficients in two variables, thus also as functions on $4\Bbb{Z}_2$, and $\log(1+4r)\equiv 4r \bmod 8r$ immediate from the Taylor series

Comment: @reuns Here I will  write some of the things I understand: The reason for the first equality is that for $b \in 1+ 4 \Bbb Z_2$, we have $|\log(b)|_2=0$ (Why? At least I can not see it.) The second equality is clear. I can not see the reason for the third equality. The fourth equality follows from the fact that $|b|_2=0$. If I can see the reason for the first and the third equality, then everything is solved and $\log$ is an isometry.

Comment: Since the $2$-adic valuation of $\dfrac{\log 5}{\log 13}$ is zero, we can conclude that $a_0=1$. That's all that I can compute!

Comment: You first use the expansion of $\log$ to calculate $\log(5)$ and $\log(13)$ up to some high precision (say $20$) and then do the division.

Comment: Very interesting to know that such computations can be done with Sage. BUT, I have a problem. I have taken a $\approx 2  \times 10^{-7}$ rational approximation of $\log(5)/\log(13)$, i.e., $539/859$. Then, doing like you have done, I obtain a quite different decomposition  : $1 + 2^6 + 2^{11} + 2^{12} + 2^{13} + 2^{14} + 2^{15} + 2^{16} + 2^{18} + 2^{19} + O(2^{20})$. How do you explain it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Your approximation is an approximation in the archimedean topology, not a $2$-adic approximation.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your answer...